# How to enable visibility panel on the site

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, panel

I have a big problem. I have a panel and a gridview on the site. Panel is outside gridview. I would like to do something like this:

```
protected void GridViewProfile_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{   
    String userName = GridViewProfile.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, "Doctor"))
    {
        ContentPlaceHolder contentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
        ((Panel)contentPlaceHolder.FindControl("PanelVisits")).Visible = true;
    }
    Membership.DeleteUser(userName, true);
}
```

Unfortunately, it isn't working. When I click on the button "Delete", panel isn't visible. Why? Please, help me write correct code.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting into the `if` statement?

Comment: Yes. I have other if statement to "Patient" and it good works. I don't change visibility control there, but that good works.

Comment: Why you are trying to find it in masterpae? Just do like this: `PanelVisits.Visible = true;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your panel inside UpdatePanel as in the following example:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False"        
    ID="UpdatePanel1"        
    UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- Your panel markup here -->
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And then on server side update your code to the following:

```
((Panel)contentPlaceHolder.FindControl("PanelVisits")).Visible = true;
UpdatePanel1.Update();
```

This will apply changes on client side because update panel will be updated.